# How to upgrade using visual studio install 2017 by setup file

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

I am using the visual studio installer 2017 in VS2017. But, I don't know how to update the setup file. 
I changed installer version from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2. And I execute follows code.

```
Process p = new Process();
            logger.Info(path);
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/i C:\\file.msi /quiet";
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

But, It is not worked. how to upgrade?
I want to install quiet option and by another process .